# How do I mock returns values of API's when my API code has been generated by OpenAPI Generator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, openapi-generator

I have generated some API code based on an OpenAPI spec. The code got generated fine. Then I built it and installed it in my main project. I did not publish the package to a registry due to corporate restrictions. The built API package is just in my main project in a different folder.

Now I am testing my Vue component which calls a couple of API's using the generated code. When I mock axios using jest.mock('axios') and define all the calls and return values, I get an undefined back.

What I am thinking is that the axios I am using in my Jest test, is a different instance than the one used by the generated code, so it doesn't get mocked.

I am importing axios just regularly like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Then I have a big array of objects with stub responses, which I made smaller, below:

```
const stubs = [
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: `/cases/${CASE_ID_SUCCESS}`,
    response: getCaseSuccess,
    isSuccessResponse: true,
  }
]
```

This is how I map over the array and mock all the responses:

```
const setupAxiosMock = (axios, stubs) => axios.request.mockImplementation(({ url, method }) => {
  const stub = stubs
    .find((element) => element.path === new URL(url).pathname && element.method === method);
  if (!stub) {
    console.error('No matching stub was found! Please fix your test');
  }
  if (stub.isSuccessResponse) {
    return Promise.resolve(stub.response);
  }
  return Promise.reject(stub.response);
});

export default setupAxiosMock;
```

Then when a call is made from my code to the API, above will mock the return value.

I tried importing the axios instance from the node_modules from the API code, but that doesn't work.

I don't really know how to mock those calls properly now. Does anyone know?

Comment: Please, don't describe your code but post, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . "What I am thinking is that the axios I am using in my Jest test" - who knows?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.